# creating a file upload function with titanium

Tags: titanium

I'm supposed to develop a mobile app for moodle using android on titanium studio. And I have been searching for days for any helpful article on how to get a file chooser dialog to work on android. Most of the tutes offer image upload but I need to upload .pdf and zip files from mobile. I have already tried fileChooserDialog() and folderChooseDialog() to no avail. Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a file chooser out of the box, as apps usually send files to each other internally. You can roll your own using ListViews though easily..

- Build a list of all the files you're interested in. (https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem.File-method-getDirectoryListing)
- Loop through the list omitting any file types you don't want and build the list
- When the user selects a file capture the click event and upload that file.
- Style however you want..

Comment: This link gives 404.